# How to assign generic map as super class in kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm wondering how to correctly use the in/out variance modifiers in this particular case.

I have a generic `Map` with a specific implementation type and I'd like to assign it to a variable under a more generic type:

```
var generalMap: Map<SimpleExpression<Any>, Any> = emptyMap()
var specificMap: Map<StringExpression, String?> = makeSomeMap()

generalMap = specificMap // this assignment won't compile :(
```

Also, `StringExpression` extends `SimpleExpression<String>`. I've tried monkeying with the `out` variance modifier a few different ways on the `generalMap` definition:

```
var generalMap: Map<out SimpleExpression<Any>, out Any?> = emptyMap()
```

...but unfortunately ran into the same compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such assignment is only possible if `SimpleExpression<T>` **only produces** T value. If so, make your interface or class declaration as following:

```
interface SimpleExpression<out T>
```

The next thing you have to change it is declaration of `generalMap`. Add `out` variance to `SimpleExpression<..>` and make `Any` nullable:

```
var generalMap: Map<out SimpleExpression<Any>, Any?> = emptyMap()
```

After that compiler allows you to assign `specificMap` to `generalMap` safely.

In case if `T` in `SimpleExpression` is produced and consumed as well (has methods like `fun consume(t: T)` and `fun produce(): T`) then you should make your declaration of `generalMap` like this:

```
var generalMap: Map<out SimpleExpression<*>, Any?> = emptyMap()
```

Answer (score 2):

`Map` is not variant on the key type, as it occurs both in `in` position to `.get()` and `out` position from `.keys()`. It's not safe to treat it as `out` because

```
var specificMap: Map<StringExpression, String?> = makeSomeMap()
var generalMap: Map<SimpleExpression<Any>, Any> = specificMap
generalMap[intExpression]  // specificMap.get(not a StringExpression)
```

That being said, there is nothing stopping you from making an unchecked cast if you believe this does not cause any actual problems with the specific `Map` implementation returned by `makeSomeMap()`.